# Request clips from Youtube videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Does the Youtube API (or any API, whether free or paid) provide a facility to request a specified chunk of a video? For example, can I request just the section from 4:37 to 4:39 of video ID xch8e2h23nw?

Alternatively, is there another youtube-like service that can do this?

I specifically want to grab tiny chunks of youtube video programmatically to use as part of a creative video mashup app.

Answer (score 0):

This is only supported by the AS3 video player and controlled by the "start" and "end" parameters.

```
<object width="560" height="315">
<param name="movie" value="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&fs=1&start=10&end=20"</param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3&fs=1&start=10&end=20"
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  allowscriptaccess="always"
  width="560" height="315">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Hmmm.. sorry I should have mentioned I need a way to do this programmatically. The above might be able to hacked into a "programmatic" method somehow, but it would require handling/processing massive amounts of data, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @themirror did you got the solution for the problem, you asked? If yes can you add your answer here. As i am too looking at for similar requirement.